# Upper bound for sum of $k2^k$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm looking at the sum
\begin{align*}
C_p \gamma \sum_{k=1}^N k 2^{k\left(\frac{p}{2} -1 \right)} + 2 n^{\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{p}}
\end{align*}
where $C_p$ is some constant depending on $p$ and $\gamma >1$. In Theorem 3.8. in

> Shahar Mendelson, *Rademacher Averages and Phase Transitions in
>   Glivenko–Cantelli Classes*, IEEE Transactions on Information Theory **48** issue 1 (2002) pp 251–263, doi:[10.1109/18.971753](https://doi.org/10.1109/18.971753), ([pdf](https://maths-people.anu.edu.au/~mendelso/papers/published/journal/IEEE-Rad.pdf))

it is stated that for $N = \frac{1}{p} \log_2 n$, $p>2$, the following inequality holds
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^N k 2^{k\left(\frac{p}{2} -1 \right)} \leq C_p n^{\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{p}}.
\end{align*}
I can't see how i could derive this inequality. For instance take $p=6$  and then the $N$-th summand would be $n^{\frac{1}{3}} \log n^{\frac{1}{6}}$ and the right hand side would be $n^{\frac{1}{3}}$. Seems odd to me. Am I missing something here?

If this inequality holds, I would appreciate a hint. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Perhaps the index of your summation is $k$.

Comment: A closed formula for $\sum_{k=1}^N k x^k$ might be helpful. To derive this, just integrate with respect to $x$.

Comment: You're right. I changed it to $k$. Thank you, i'll try the approach you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

The inequality 
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^N k 2^{k\left(\frac{p}{2} -1 \right)} \leq C_p n^{\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{p}}
\end{align*}
for $p>2$ is incorrect. Indeed, its left-hand side is no less than the $N$th summand in the sum, which is 
$$N2^{N\left(\frac{p}{2} -1 \right)}=\tfrac1p\,n^{\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{p}}\,\log_2 n, 
$$
which is much greater than $C_p n^{\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{p}}$ for any real constant $C_p$ depending only on $p$ and all large enough $n$.